# How to generate excel file with multiple worksheets and pivot tables and charts without using any external dlls?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, epplus

I need to generate an excel reports which consists of a worksheet A which has data and another worksheet B which has pivot table based on data on A. Worksheet B also has a 2D column chart based on pivot table. Then the worksheets A and B are repeated(iterated) based on data for different entities in the SQL server database. This is the requirement.
                    I achieved this by creating a C# console application. I had to use EPPLUS dll since the target server doesn't have MS-Excel installed. Now the twist is my company only allows certain approved third party software to be used and EPPLUS isn't among them(Yes! Stupid of me to invest time without checking this first). I can request them to consider but I don't know if they approve or how long they may take to approve. My colleagues suggested me to look for alternatives. Here are the option I have in my mind.

1. Get MS-Excel installed on the server and modify C# application to get the work done without EPPLUS. The question I have here how hard is it to generate pivot tables and charts using this option.
2. SSIS. I'm fairly proficient and generated excels before. But I don't know how pivot tables and charts can be generated using SSIS.

I hope this is clear. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: SSIS can only push data into a spreadsheet. It will not be able to create any of the visualizations for you

Comment: If you have the option to actually install excel on the server then that is probably your strongest option.  Any other option comes either with restrictions and/or cost money (beyond the extra office license).  Then you can just code against the excel dom which is very straight forward (and similar to epplus).  Plenty of examples your can google but check this out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084

Answer (score 0):

You can create the desired layout as an SSRS report, and use the "Export to Excel" option.

Naturally there will be a learning curve if you've never used SSRS.